# Using COUNTIFS with different date formats

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate the totals of a column when the date column is within a certain month. The value to find is in a different date format to the format in the criteria range and I can't figure out how create a formula using the two different date formats. Here are the columns where I am trying to get the totals from:

[image]

Here is where I am trying to count the rows when it falls within a certain month and year:

[image]

This is the formula I have created but this doesn't work and just returns 0:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$27, YEAR(G3), $A$3:$A$27, MONTH(G3))
```

I have also tried this but it is still returning 0:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$27, "=YEAR(G3)", $A$3:$A$27, "=MONTH(G3)")
```

Comment: You could use an array, so having top table in A1:A10 and bottom in C1:C12, you could have the following `=sum(--(year($A$1:$A$10)=(year(C1))*(month($A$1:$A$10)=month(C1)))`  This is an array formula so press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

Comment: Assuming G3 is actually 1 Jan 21 formatted to display mmm-yy, you could use: `=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$27, ">="&G3, $A$3:$A$27, "<="&EOMONTH(G3,0))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format is irrelevant **if your dates are REAL dates**

- If your dates are "real" dates, merely formatted a certain way
- And if your Months are also real dates where the date is actually the first of the month,

Then:

```
=COUNTIFS(Dates,">="&B15,Dates,"<=" &EOMONTH(B15,0))
```

Where `Dates` is the Named Range containing your list of dates, and `B15` contains your month/year formatted first of the month date.

If your months column is not the first of the month, then a minor change is all that is needed to convert the first criteria to the first of the month:

```
=COUNTIFS(Dates,">="&DATE(YEAR(B15),MONTH(B15),1),Dates,"<=" &EOMONTH(B15,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What does the `&` represent when using `">="&B15`?

Comment: @BailP concatenation operator